# sample, replace=F in R

Tags: r, joint-distribution

I was wondering how can I determine joint and marginal distribution in R. I believe I should use the function `sample` and for my exercise also `replace=F` and also `for` with iterations.

I was in hospital and I missed some classes in Probability, so I would be really grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: What do you mean by "determine joint and marginal distribution"? If you mean determine the theoretical distribution of some random varible, R won't be able to help you. You could obtain an empirical estimate of the distribution using R

Comment: Well English is not my native language so I jsut translated it and thought it was right, but I guess it was not correct. So I think it's the suggestion you made that I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sample(x, size, replace=F)` gives a rerandomization of `x` (i.e. a shuffling of `x`). If you combine a loop to rerandomize by variables in `x`, then you preserve the marginal distributions of each variable, but make them independent of one another.

Should you have said `replace=T` that would give a bootstrap sample of `x`, for `size` number of bootstrap samples of `x`.

Comment: Thanks. Well we have some number of balls of different colours and we should choose 2 of them. X is for the number of yellow balls and Y for green ones. We should determine the probability of choosing yellow and green balls (there's a table: X0-Y0, X1-Y0, X2-Y0, X0-Y1...). In the assignment there's said that we should use "sample", "replace=F", "for" and the number of iterations (e.g. 1000).

Comment: For bootstrap, wouldn't you be sampling WITH replacement? Without replacement you would get the original sample back since the size of each bootstrap sample is equal to the samplle size of x.

Comment: Good heavens, I totally got that backward! Thanks... caffeine. Edited now.

Comment: Yes Christy, you are choosing two balls without replacement, so replace =F.